# Why can't I see the Angular 2 Directives on doing Inspect Element in Chrome Browser?

Tags: html, angular, debugging, dom

I am beginner to Angular 2 (I've worked on AngularJS) and my concern is that while using AngularJS, I am able to see AngularJS Directives on doing Inspect Element in Chrome Browser. However, the same is not the case with Angular 2/2+ versions i.e. I cannot find the Angular Directives anymore when I do Inspect Element.

Am I missing something? Or is there a plugin or some configuration introduced in Angular 2/2+ which I must do to be able to view the Angular Directives on doing Inspect Element in Chrome?

Following are the images to explain further: -

[image: My Current Code]

Note the highlighted part in the above image.

[image: What appears on inspecting the element in Chrome Browser]

Notice how the Angular Directives namely **ngModel** and **blur event** aren't shown in the Html on Inspecting the DOM Element.

If anyone might enlighten me on the situation that'd be really helpful.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Because they are invalid attributes of the html DOM elements. When they are transpiled they are simply replaced with classes, custom attributes, etc.

In Angular 1, `(blur)` & `[(ngModel)]` we're written as `ng-blur` & `ng-model` respectively that need not to be transpiled because they were non-standard data attributes.

Comment: So then, as like in AngularJS isn't there a way to see which of my DOM elements have events associated to them? like **blur** or which of the elements having **ngModel** have what variable assigned to it in Angular 2/2+? 

I mean it's really tough to know what is what and has what all events and directives assigned to them when Inspecting Element via. a Browser.

Do you know any way to let Browser be able to show the Angular Directives of Angular 2/2+